# How do I speed up “ls -l” on a network file system (NFS)?

Tags: filesystems, distributed-filesystems, nfs

I have a NFS volume mounted in the following way:

```
theHostname.com:/path/on/theHostname on /local/path type nfs (rw,nosuid,addr=10.0.0.54)
```

The `/local/path` directory has 30_000 files.
When I do a `ls` in `/local/path` it takes about 1s on average. When I do a `ls -l` it takes about 60 seconds on average.

Is there a way to speed up `ls -l` on NFS other than speeding up the network connection?

Comment: ls only reads the directory, with -l it has to read the directory plus all 30000 inodes (because ownership and permission bits are stored there, not in the directory).

Comment: The slowest part is getting file attributes for each single file. You can a bit speed it up by increasing nfs client cache life time. Check acregmin and acregmax mount options ( man nfs )